# Create resource group as parallel from console application in different subscription

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-powershell

Query: I want to create resource group as parallel from console application in different subscription.

I have developed small console application. I have installed Azure Powershell version 3.0.  invoke powershell by system.automation.dll from console application. Please find the code that i have used

C# console application:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p=new Program();

            var resourceGroups=new List<ResourceGroup>();
            resourceGroups.Add(new ResourceGroup { AdUsername = "AdUsername", AdPassword = "AdPassword", SubscriptionId = "SubscriptionId1"});
            resourceGroups.Add(new ResourceGroup { AdUsername = "AdUsername", AdPassword = "AdPassword", SubscriptionId = "SubscriptionId2" });
            resourceGroups.Add(new ResourceGroup { AdUsername = "AdUsername", AdPassword = "AdPassword", SubscriptionId = "SubscriptionId2" });
            resourceGroups.Add(new ResourceGroup { AdUsername = "AdUsername", AdPassword = "AdPassword", SubscriptionId = "SubscriptionId3" });
            resourceGroups.Add(new ResourceGroup { AdUsername = "AdUsername", AdPassword = "AdPassword", SubscriptionId = "SubscriptionId1" });

            Parallel.ForEach(resourceGroups, (resourceGroup,pls,index)=> ParallelAccessPowershellScript(resourceGroup, index));

        }

        private static void ParallelAccessPowershellScript(ResourceGroup resourceGroup,long i)
        {
            try
            {
                string scriptPath = @"Microsoft_Image\loadjsontemplate.ps1";
                var addParametersToScriptFile = new Command(scriptPath);
                addParametersToScriptFile.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("AdUsername", resourceGroup.AdUsername));
                addParametersToScriptFile.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("AdPassword", resourceGroup.AdPassword));
                addParametersToScriptFile.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("SubscriptionId",resourceGroup.SubscriptionId));
                addParametersToScriptFile.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ResourceGroupName", "testparallel"+i));
                addParametersToScriptFile.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("LocationName", "location"));

                var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                runspace.Open();
                var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
                var scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

                scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned");
                var pipeline = powerShell.Runspace.CreatePipeline();
                pipeline.Commands.Add(addParametersToScriptFile);
                pipeline.Invoke();
                runspace.Close();
                runspace.Dispose();
                powerShell.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {


            }


        }
    }
```

Powershell script

```
param
(
 [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,HelpMessage="Azure Resource Group name,virtual network,availability are created in this name")]
    [String]
    $ResourceGroupName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,HelpMessage="Azure Resource Group created in this location")]
    [String]
    $LocationName,
    [string]
    $AdPassword,
    [string]
    $AdUserName,
    [string]
    $SubscriptionId
)
#login into powershell using active directory credentials
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $AdPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($AdUserName, $securePassword)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential  
#select the subscription as user chosed 
$AzureInfo = Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -TenantId $AzureInfo.TenantId
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName
```

But all resource group created same subscription. How can i created resourcegroup as parallel in different subscription?

Comment: Does the PowerShell script create RGs in different subscriptions when you run it outside of C#?  (it looks like it should)

Comment: Hi, yes, when i tried from powershell window its created propertly. But when i am trying in c#, it conflicting with other session.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if the problem is in the PS side or the C# code... One thing you could try is using Set-AzureRMContext (instead of select subscription).  Though something tells me it's related to how the context is created (which I'm less familiar with).

Comment: Hi, i am also tried with AzureRMContext. But still the exceptions occurred.

Comment: Ok, lemme see if I can find someone who might be more familiar with the C# side of things...